# BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 3265: Method [validateMaz] does not exist

Tags: laravel

Please help task controller.

This is a error when I hit the submit button

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|maz:255',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: what is this Method[validateMaz]

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule named `maz`. I guess what you meant is `max` rule.
Replace `maz` with `max` in your validation.

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
       'name' => 'required|max:255',
   ]);
}
```